# Making button auto click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game, when a letter is complete I want the next word to spell to be selected automatically. At the moment the user has to click the button to go to the next.

At the moment I have this

```
var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist) {
    $('.minibutton').click('enable');


} else {
    $('.minibutton').click('disable');
    $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
    audio.play();
    $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
    pic.show();
}


});
```

I have tried replacing the line...

```
$('.minibutton').click('enable');
```

to...

```
$('.minibutton').trigger('click')
```

and it won't work, any ideas?

**THANKS**

Comment: Did you try `$('.minibutton').click();`

Comment: Yes I have it does the same thing as if I had "enable" there @Praveen Kumar

Comment: No. It just enables it to be pressed. I need the button to perform its function without the user pressing it. @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Actually what you have want button click event or button enable/disable?

Comment: I want to get rid of the button by making its function automatic when triggered. button click event. So if(noExist) then autoclick else no autoclick @Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider refactoring so that the action of going to the next word is independent of how it is triggered. That would be cleaner and you don't have to do tricks like faking clicks.

```
function gotoNextWord(){
    // ...
}
```

and setup

```
$('.minibutton').on('click', gotoNextWord);
```

and I'm not entirely grokking your code, but it would become something like this:

```
// ...
if (noExist) {
    gotoNextWord();    

} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could give me a fiddle example? http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/cTGGA/6/ @Supr

Comment: Like I said, I don't fully follow your code, but I've done the refactoring here: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/cTGGA/7/ That one executes the same code as a click in place of `$('.minibutton').click('enable');` when `noExist == true`, but I don't know if it -- as a whole -- works the way you want. You might end up in an infinite loop since the gotoNextWord action is calling itself...

Comment: This fiddle does the same as what mine did before though. @Supr

Comment: @m0onio, Then that just verifies that the problem is elsewhere, as suspected by some of the other answers. Review the higher level logic :)

Answer (score 0):

What about just: `$('.minibutton').click();`

Answer (score 0):

to Disable

```
$('.minibutton').unbind('click').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

to enable

```
$('.minibutton').unbind('click');
```

Comment: It is enabled I want it to work without the user clicking it @acrashik

Comment: The OP wants to emulate a `click()` function on it. Not to disable.

Comment: well $('.minibutton').trigger('click'); should trigger click event... this line of code is just what you need, if it's not working, then where is an error somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (noExist) {
    $('.minibutton').click('enable'); // if your button successfully enable then write below line after it.
    $('.minibutton').click();
}
```